# Unable to create a folder just after deletion in android

Tags: android, directory

I am unable to create a folder in the same location with the same name just after deleting the folder with the same name(manually,deletion is manually,not programmatically). I am trying to create folder using

```
mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()
```

I dont know why this happens, also some times I see a junk file of size 0KB with the same name after I have deleted the file, I assume this is preventing the new folder creation. Those who have an insight into folder structure, pleas throw some light into this topic.

Below is the image of the dummy file that is created after the deletion.

[image]

Comment: `mediaStorageDir.delete()` and `mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()`  are returning boolean. Are you getting true on delete()  and false on mkdirs()? Without any exception?

Comment: Delete I am doing manually, not programmatically, after that I am doing mkdirs programmatically, it is returning false, I want to know the reason for the same.

Comment: Also as a note, I am checking whether is it exists using .exists, which returns false, after that only I am trying to make the folder.

Comment: With which application do you delete your file manually? Maybe try an other to see if it does the same thing?

Comment: I am using File Manager to delete the file, also as a side note, I am not able to create a file manually(not via program) as well, it says "Some file operation failed".

Comment: There are many "File Manager" apps, I can't reproduce it if I don't know which one exactly. I created a folder using boolean b = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"testFolder").mkdirs(); and it worked. I went in ES File explorer, deleted it, then launched again my application which created the folder correctly. Be careful with the permission, I wrote ANDROID.PERMISSION (copy/paste) and it didn't work, I put "android.permission" and it worked.

Comment: I am convinced that the problem lies in the method which I create the folder, not in which I delete the folder. Because manually created folder doesn't cause any problems.